collectAsStateWithLifecycle() collects SharedFlow only after clicking a button
I found that SharedFlow is collected correctly by collectAsStateWithLifecycle() only when I click a button instead of waiting to timeout or when I change replay to 1. In other cases it is collected only once. StateFlow works correctly. Do you know any explanation of this behavior?
Here are code snippets:
In ViewModel:
private val _question = MutableSharedFlow<Result<Question>>(
    replay = 1,
)
val question
    get() = _question.asSharedFlow()

private val _questionNumber = MutableStateFlow(0)
val questionNumber
    get() = _questionNumber.asStateFlow()

suspend fun nextQuestion() {
    val questionWithIndex = questionIterator.next()
    _question.emit(Result.success(questionWithIndex.value))
    _questionNumber.value = questionWithIndex.index + 1
}


Screen:
val questionResult by questionViewModel.question
    .collectAsStateWithLifecycle(initialValue = null)

LaunchedEffect(questionResult) {
    givenAnswerViewModel.clearSelectedAnswers()
    questionResult?.fold(
        onSuccess = {
            isLoading = false
            question = it
            timerViewModel.start()
        },
        onFailure = {
            val messageRes = getHttpFailureMessage(it as? Exception)
            snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(context.getString(messageRes))
        },
    )
}

val sendAnswers: () -> Unit = {
    timerViewModel.clear()
    givenAnswerViewModel.addAnswer(question)

    coroutineScope.launch {
        if (questionViewModel.isQuestionLast()) {
            givenAnswerViewModel.sendAnswers(
                userUUID = userViewModel.userUuid,
                token = userViewModel.token,
            )
        } else {
            questionViewModel.nextQuestion()
        }
    }
}

if (timeLeft == 0L) {
    sendAnswers()
}

sendAnswers is also invoked on clicking a button.

Replay is 0 by default. Not viable to use something without replay for State because the state is immediately lost if it happens to change while a composition isn’t happening simultaneously.

Does it mean that recomposition isn't caused by the state change, but state is collected only during recomposition?

I’m not sure I understand your question. If you use a SharedFlow without replay, changing the value in the flow might not change State value at all because the new value might be skipped. It will only change for compositions that have already composed and are still visible at the time the value is changed. Then those compositions will recompose.

So, SharedFlow's value change can be omitted if it'll happen during recomposition?

If the emission happened right before composition started, it would definitely drop that one. I’m not sure if it could also drop ones that occur while a recomposition is in progress.

As Tenfour04 already explained in the comments: A SharedFlow has a replay value of 0. That means it works more akin to a regular Flow: When you collect it, you will only get the next value that is emitted, you do not get the past values replayed. It's like observing a stream of data: When you start collecting you only see what happens from now on, there is no history.
That is different for a StateFlow because it has a replay value of 1. Moreover, a StateFlow can only constructed with an initial value, so there will always be one value. When you collect a StateFlow you get the latest value (the initial value or whatever was emitted lastly) replayed.
This is what makes a StateFlow behave with a State semantic: It's like a variable with a value that you can observe for changes. That is the same semantic that a Compose State has. Technically its very different, but they both behave the same. That is the reason why a StateFlow can easily be converted to a Compose State by calling collectAsStateWithLifecycle.
The SharedFlow on the other hand is like an incomplete State: It can be observed for changes, but it doesn't start out with an initial value (that's why you need to provide one for collectAsStateWithLifecycle) and unless its replay value is set to 1 it will behave differently when you start collecting.
Bottom line: Only expose StateFlow in your view model. You can convert any Flow into a StateFlow with stateIn. Provide the viewModelScope as parameter. When the underlying flow is a MutableStateFlow then just apply asStateFlow() as you already do.
